# Shortcut to execute a Windows PowerShell command

Tags: windows, powershell, exe

I'm currently developing a discord bot and I'm quite new to programming:

To start the bot, I have to open a new windows PowerShell, navigate to the discord bot's folder and activate it by using the `node .`. To make this a lot quicker, I would like to make a .exe file to do this commands for me and execute the following commands:

1. open a new Powershell window
2. navigate to the folder: `cd desktop/discord bot`
3. start the bot with `node .`
4. leave the window open so I can read all the logs from the bot

It would be wonderfull if someone knew how to do this or know where I can search for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that comes here and what to know how i did it.. I make a text file and converted the empty text file to an .bat file (google how to do that). Then with microsoft visual studio edit the file. I wrote only `node .` in the file and to worked great.